# ANTLR4: zero or one times

Tags: antlr, antlr4, grammar

I'm working on defining a grammar using ANTLR4 and Java. For Integers, I want a number that mat be preceeded by a minus sign. I know it is possible to do it like this:

```
integer: '-' (DIGIT)* | DIGIT* ;
```

But I was wondering if there is a symbol (similar to the *) that assures a the minus sign occurs zero or one time:

```
integer: ('-')<some symbol here> (DIGIT)* ;
```

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Yes, it's the `?`, which means *zero or once* (optional). Also, the `*` means *zero ore more*. You probably want `+` which means *once or more*:

```
integer : '-'? DIGIT+ ;
```

Comment: It worked, thanks! Also changed * to + thanks for the feedback.